Solving second-order nonlinear ODE $x^3y''=(y-xy')^2$
Given second-order nonlinear differential equation: $x^3\cdot y''=(y-xy')^2$
I have no idea how to solve it. Give me a hint!

Is it $-x^3y''=(y-xy')^2$, or is it $x^3y''=(y-xy')^2$ ?

Where did the question come from?

Maple solves it  by finding 2 integrating factors.  It gives solution as
$$
y = -x \ln \left(\frac{c_{1} x -c_{2}}{x}\right)
$$

Just make $y(x)=x,z(x)$

Please tell us why you are asking the question, what you have done so far and what your thoughts are behind the question/task. Because in its current state the question does not meet the quality standards of Math.SE, but is more similar to a question of the form "Can you please solve my problem.".

Given differential equation:
$$x^3y''=(y-xy')^2\tag{1}$$
which is a second-order non-linear ODE.
Substitute $u=\frac yx$ so that $y'=u+xu'$ and $y''=2u'+xu''$.
We get the following new second-order non-linear ODE:
$$x^3(2u'+xu'')=(ux-ux-x^2u'^2)^2\implies xu''+2u'=xu'^2\tag{2}$$
Again, substitute $v=xu'$ so that $v'=xu''+u'$.
We get:
$$v'+\frac vx=x\cdot\frac{v^2}{x^2}\implies v'x+v=v^2\tag{3}$$
Now, it is obvious that the ODE $(3)$ can be solved by the separation of variables as follows:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm  dv}{v(v-1)}=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}\implies\ln\frac{v-1}{v}=\ln x+\ln C_1\implies v=\frac{1}{1-C_1x}=\frac{1}{Cx+1}\tag{4}$$
Then, we have: $$u'=\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}=\frac vx=\frac{1}{x(Cx+1)}=\frac1x-\frac{C}{Cx+1}\tag{5}$$
The integration of $(5)$ leads to:
$$u=\frac yx=\ln x-\ln(Cx+1)-\ln C_2=\ln\left(\frac{x}{C_2(Cx+1)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{c_1x+c_2}\right)=-\ln\left(\frac{c_1x+c_2}{x}\right)\tag{6}$$
So, the required solution to the given ODE is: $$\boxed{y=-x\ln\left(\frac{c_1x+c_2}{x}\right)}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants of integration that can be determined from the boundary conditions.
Also, see what WolframAlpha says about the solution.
